# $ABC$ be a triangle $R_a$, $R_b$, $R_c$ are the radii of Lucas Circles of $ABC$. Prove that:

Tags: inequality, circles, triangles, area, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$ABC$ be a triangle $R_a$, $R_b$, $R_c$ are the radii of Lucas Circles of $ABC$. Prove that:
$$R_a+R_b+R_c\geq \dfrac {8.\triangle}{(1+\sqrt {3})^2.R}$$
where $\triangle$ and $R$ are area and circumradius of $ABC$ respectively.

I couldn't get anything to even start. Please help me.

Edit:
 I read about Lucas Circles from https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c2899h1233399_lucas_circles 
I didn't understand the explanation from this point further:
Then draw perpendiculars to the side from each of $...$

Comment: what are the Lucas circles in a triangle?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, No idea about that.

Comment: see here https://www.scribd.com/document/318116922/Lucas-s-Inner-Circles

Comment: What is the purpose of solving this problem if you do not even know anything about its subject?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I am preparing for exams where such ques. might be asked!

Comment: Better start studying the definitions: first things first.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, You are right. But, I am preparing informally at home so not much sources and thus those problems which I find difficult post here.

Comment: All right, in such a case I suggest an improvement, i.e. to add the definition of Lucas circle and what is known about its radius.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Ok sir. I'll try to learn from google and update it.

Answer (score 1):

[Lucas circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasCircles.html) arise in the problem of inscribing a square inside a triangle:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The radius of the $A$-Lucas circle is given by $R_A=\frac{R}{1+\frac{2aR}{bc}}$ and these circles are pairwise tangent. Additionally, they are tangent to the circumcircle of $ABC$.

**Hint**: what happens by applying [Descartes' circle theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesCircleTheorem.html) to the configuration given by the Lucas circles and the circumcircle?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a^2=x$, $b^2=y$ and $c^2=z$.

Hence, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{R}{1+\frac{2a\cdot\frac{abc}{4\Delta}}{bc}}\geq\frac{8\Delta}{(1+\sqrt3)^2R}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2\Delta+a^2}\geq\frac{2}{(2+\sqrt3)R^2}.$$
Now, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2\Delta+a^2}\geq\frac{9}{6\Delta+a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$9(2+\sqrt3)R^2\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2+6\Delta)$$ or
$$\frac{9(2+\sqrt3)a^2b^2c^2}{16\Delta^2}\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+12\Delta$$ or
$$\frac{9(2+\sqrt3)xyz}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2xy-x^2)}\geq2(x+y+z)+3\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2xy-x^2)},$$
which is true because 
$$9xyz\geq(x+y+z)\sum\limits_{cyc}(2xy-x^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)\geq0,$$
which is Schur and
$$3\sqrt3xyz\geq\sqrt{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2xy-x^2)\right)^3}$$ or
$$27x^2y^2z^2\geq\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(2xy-x^2)\right)^3$$ or
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}\geq2(xy+xz+yz)$$ is Schur again:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left((x^2+\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt[3]{x^4y^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2y^4}\right)\geq2(xy+xz+yz).$$
Done!

Comment: How did you use $\sum_{cyc}$?

Comment: @Ramanujan For example $\sum\limits_{cyc}x=x+y+z$, $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z)=x^2y+x^2z+y^2z+y^2x+z^2x+z^2y$ and similar

Comment: How did you get the LHS of first statement?

Comment: @Ramanujan It's just which we need to prove: $R_a+R_b+R_c\geq...$